# mpg123 for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, mp3, lamemp3

I developed an Android app that reads an .mp3-file, does some manipulation on the PCM data and writes the result to another .mp3-file. So far, I have been using [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) for decoding and LAME (with NDK) for mp3-encoding. Everything works fine - the only issue is that JLayer is very slow ([as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645087/slow-mp3-decoding-on-android-using-jlayer)). Thus, I would like to switch to [mpg123](http://www.mpg123.de/) that presumably is very fast. For LAME there are nice Android NDK [tutorials](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do;jsessionid=lt8j6Fp68oJN87E5O__S--MWq5lKRDVFOcoiQWUmyMsdDJ07PmiZ!-491879268?v=T000000090) around, but for mpg123 I have not found anything. The only functionality I need is to decode an mp3-file framewise and obtain the data as PCM. I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020279/how-to-use-mpg123-in-android),  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494499/mp3-decoding-on-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741701/android-fastest-way-to-decode-mp3-to-pcm-data) question, but my problem remains unsolved. As I am new to Android NDK I have two questions:

- Does any of you know a step-by-step tutorial showing how to compile mpg123 for Android using the NDK? In particular, I do not know what the Android.mk and the wrapper.c should look like.
- Does any of you have a good alternative? In principle the only thing I am looking for is a fast version of JLayer because the functionality is excellent whereas the performance is poor.

Any help will greatly be appreciated!